# Storing new rows in view object at the commit time only

Tags: user-interface, oracle11g, row, oracle-adf

[image: Adding new rows in ADF table]

As you can see from the image attached. The user will be able to add new `rows` to the `table` (which is based on some (`view object`). the (**Add**) button is invoking `action method` from the `Bean` class where it create new `row` and insert the (**Forward From**) and (**Forward Date**) in it. The (**Request Number**) is auto generated value **BUT** it is not simply sequence number, it is a combination of many component that is generated based on other user input and they are not showing in the image.

Problem is since the (**Request number**) could be changed based on user input I do not want to store any thing in `view object` unless the (**Request Number**) is finalize which is only at (**commit**) time. So, I do not want to store new `rows` in the `view object` and I know already they may change.

So, I am thinking of a way to have the same `User Interface` i.e `Table` and the tow `text boxes` but they are not mapped to a `view object`. So, what I need is temporary space to store these data and in the **commit** time I will store them in `view object` where I am sure that the (**Request Number**) is finalized.

I am using `Jdeveloper 11g with ADF Technology`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the answer in this thread:

[Storing new rows in view object at the commit time only](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3529357)

The answer is to use the concept of the `Transient View object` where it will hold data before `commit` time. At the `commit` time the data will be stored in the actual `view object` that is mapped to the Database table.